# Checking token validity with identity server

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am setting up a React front end that authenticates against Identity server 4 using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow.

Our reason for choosing the password credentials flow is that this is a first party integration and we intend to integrate with an app in the future.

We want to constantly poll the identity server from the client's react instance to check whether their token is still valid and log them out if it has expired.
 This is inspired by the checkSessionIFrame in Implicit flow which polls the server to check whether the session_state has changed.

The introspection_endpoint almost seems to be what we are looking for except that it is meant to be called by a resource server rather than the client them self.

1. Is this a sensible way to ensure that an idle client is logged out?
2. If so, what is the best way within the Identity Server 4 framework to perform this polling?

Comment: The `access_token` contains a field called `exp` which you can use to check if the token has been expired and then log out the user...

Comment: We also want to have the ability to sign out users remotely after issuing the tokens, the way that session management does.

Comment: Then you should take a look at the [Revocation Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html)

Comment: The revocation endpoint allows clients to notify the authorization server that a previously obtained refresh or access token is no longer needed. This would not allow the server to logout a user's session remotely.